# Including sums and vectors in an R function

Tags: r, function, vector, sum

I have two vectors `a` and `b`, both with 8 elements. I need to make a function which is sum[(a_i+b_i)^2] i.e I need to add the respective components, then square them, then add the squares.

I am able to write simple functions like `f(x)=5x+2` in R, but not sure how to incorporate vectors and sums...maybe a loop?

Sorry for my bad formula writing and sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new to R.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a function for sum[(a_i+b_i)^2], just do:

```
a <- 1:8  # a and b are vectors consisting of 8 elements
b <- a+10    
sum((a+b)^2) # this is what you want to do
[1] 3056
```

In order to sum and square the total:

```
sum(a+b)^2
[1] 23104
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought R would have summed the elements of each vector and squared the total.

Comment: @user1958688: If you thought that you should have looked at the output of `(a+b)^2`. You would have seen and 8-element result. Examining nested R objects is fundamental in learning the language. You need to learn to think from the "inside to outside".

Answer (score 1):

**edited**

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)

sum((x + y)^2)
```

Comment: you've created two variables: `x` and `y` and you don't use them in `sum()` instead you have `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f <- function(a,b) crossprod(a+b)
```